# @capacitor/filesystem: How to check if a folder/directory exists or not?

Tags: capacitor, capacitor-plugin

In my ionic capacitor app, I need to check if a folder exists or not on my device. But I have not found any method in the FileSystem plugin. Although there is a method for reading all the contents inside a directory.

In my case, at first, I need to check if the directory already exists or not. If it is not found, then I will create the directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In try block write the code for creating a directory. An exception will be thrown otherwise.

```
    try {
      let ret = await Filesystem.mkdir({
        path: folderName,
        directory: FilesystemDirectory.Documents,
        recursive: false,
      });
      console.log("folder ", ret);
    } catch (e) {
      //console.error("Unable to make directory", e);
    }
```

Comment: If the directory already exist , 'mkdir' will not overwrite that

Comment: it is working fine in my case. but a direct method would be better.